# Default Argument for Template Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

```
#include <cstdint>

class MyBar {};
class DifferentBar {};

class Foo{
public:
    template <class Bar = MyBar>
    Foo(uint32_t i) {}
};

int main() {
    auto pFoo1 = new Foo(3);
    auto pFoo2 = new Foo<DifferentBar>(3);
}
```

I am trying to understand why the compiler gave me an error:

```
template_ctor.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
template_ctor.cpp:14:19: error: ‘Foo’ is not a template
  auto pFoo2 = new Foo<DifferentBar>(3);
                   ^~~
```

Is it because default argument for template parameter is only valid at class level?  As when I changed to:

```
template <class Bar = MyBar>
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(uint32_t i) {}
};
```

It compiles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you cannot specify type arguments for templated constructors, they must be deduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
class Foo{
public:
    template <class Bar = MyBar>
    Foo(uint32_t i) {}
};
```

you say that `Foo` is a not-template class with a template constructor.

When you write

```
auto pFoo2 = new Foo<DifferentBar>(3);
```

you give to `Foo` a template parameter; but `Foo` is a not-template class.

So the error.

Changing `Foo` in a template class with a default parameter template

```
<class Bar = MyBar>
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(uint32_t i) {}
};
```

you have that now `new Foo<DifferentBar>(3);` is correct and compile also `new Foo(3);` because is used the default template parameter (`MyBar`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Would you mind showing how to call the constructor for the first declaration of `Foo`?  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF - simply `new Foo(3)`; in first declaration you have a template constructor without arguments; as far I know, it's impossible deduce the template types (no argument for template type deduction) and it's impossible explicit them (there isn't a syntax in C++ language for this) so `new Foo(3)` works only because there is the default template parameter (`MyBar`).

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind, could you take a look at a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389395/template-argument-deduction-failed-with-default-template-parameter)?  Thanks!